# Entity Framework Migration cascade delete is always true even WillCascadeOnDelete(false) in configuration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Why relations with  WillCascadeOnDelete(false) defined in configuration,  are always true in generated migration?

**Here is the configuration code**

```
 public class PartySuppliesConfiguration:EntityTypeConfiguration<PartySupplies>
{
    public PartySuppliesConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasRequired(x=>x.Supplier).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.SupplierId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(x => x.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(x => x.Currency).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CurrencyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(x => x.CreatedUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        Property(x => x.UnitPrice).HasColumnType("Money");
    }
}
```

**and here is the generated migration**

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "PartySupplies",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SupplierId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ProductId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UnitPrice = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    CurrencyId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    FromDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ThruDate = c.DateTime(),
                    CreatedUserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("Parties", t => t.SupplierId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("Products", t => t.ProductId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("Curencies", t => t.CurrencyId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("Users", t => t.CreatedUserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.SupplierId)
            .Index(t => t.ProductId)
            .Index(t => t.CurrencyId)
            .Index(t => t.CreatedUserId);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a silly question but have you overriden the OnModelBuilding method in DbContext and added `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add( new PartySuppliesConfiguration( ) );`? Does `PartySuppliers` have any DataAnnotations that might be overriding your entity config class? Or maybe it's derived from another class where cascadeondelete is set to true?

Comment: I noticed this today when I did not add the `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyMappingClass())` to the OnModelBuilding method.